# Easiest way to search records in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a map in Clojure something like this:

```
(def stuff #{

        {:a "help" :b "goodbye"}
        {:c "help2" :b "goodbye"}
        {:a "steve" :b "goodbye"}
        {:c "hello2" :b "sue"}
    })
```

: and I want to provide a search so that:

```
(search stuff "help")
```

: would return :

```
 #{
    {:a "help" :b "goodbye"}
    {:c "help2" :b "goodbye"}
}
```

: What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
user=> (defn search [s q] (select #(some (partial re-find (re-pattern q)) (vals %)) s))
#'user/search
user=> (search stuff "help")
#{{:a "help", :b "goodbye"} {:c "help2", :b "goodbye"}}
```

This does the trick.

Comment: Brilliant! You are a star. That worked first time. (PS. I also appreciate that you actually tested your answer before posting) :)

Comment: Only problem I have found with this is that when a record contains a value with a nil value in it then there is a null pointer exception.

Comment: Does not work as expected : would also return 'records' where the word "help" is also present as the value of :b .

Comment: @Laurent - in defense of Rayne I wanted it to return records when the word "help" was the value of :b

Comment: @Laurent That's what he wanted. Go write some Counterclockwise or something and leave me alone. ;p

Answer (score 2):

Full text search is a different topic, but if you can live with regexps I would use something like:

```
(defn match [re e]
    (re-find re (:a e))

(defn search [re m]
    (into #{} (filter (partial match re) m)))
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. When I do that (search stuff "help") it returns all four records. Thanks for trying anyway

Answer (score 1):

`(filter (comp #{"help"} :a) stuff)`: the freshly-composed function first calls `:a` on the target, then calls `#{"help"}` on the result: this returns a truthy value iff the `:a` attribute is exactly `"help"`.

Converting this into a set, and encapsulating it in a function with the arguments you want to tweak, is left as an exercise for the reader. Frankly, though, the code is so simple that it might well be shorter and more readable to rewrite it each time you want to do a "search".

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for something that can search over multiple keys though

Comment: I also did what said and looked at all the reader macros, but I could not find any macros which could convert this to a set. Thanks for the tips anyway

Comment: Huh? The function `set` does that. Why would you look for a reader macro?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood, as you mentioned using the reader in the answer.

Comment: "The reader" is you: you are currently reading this answer. To "leave something as an exercise for the reader" is an English idiom you may have missed. It comes up often in textbooks, meaning: "X can be done, but it would take a lot of space in the book and you might enjoy doing it yourself anyway." It's often a bit of a joke, too: "X can be done, but I'm too lazy to do it, so do it yourself".

Comment: Ah, thanks, I wasn't sure exactly what you meant but I know what you are talking about!! :) I did end up tweaking Rayne's answer to get rid of the nil problem I mentioned in his answer.